# Get build information from Jenkins API with jenkins_api_client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, jenkins

I'm writing a Jenkins plugin and I want to retrieve last build information (number, timestamp, build parameters) for a given job from the Jenkins API. I can do this using **jenkins_api_client** (ruby gem) with REST call and obtain it.

```
<url_to_jenkins>job/<job name>/api/json?pretty=true&tree=builds[actions[parameters[name,value]],id,number]
```

This is the output I get:

```
"{""builds""=>
[{""actions""=>
[{""parameters""=>
[{""name""=>""BUILD"", ""value""=>""APACHE""}, 
{""name""=>""CLIENT"", ""value""=>""GOOGLE""}]}, {}, {}, {}, {}], 
""id""=>""2013-03-09_07-36-49"", 
""number""=>18}]}"
```

How can I get `BUILD` and `CLIENT` values i.e., `APACHE` and `GOOGLE` in ruby?

Comment: what class is that output of? String?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it but you require [json](http://www.json.org/), this is the format of the answer.

```
require 'json'

reply = "{""builds""=>
[{""actions""=>
[{""parameters""=>
[{""name""=>""BUILD"", ""value""=>""APACHE""}, 
{""name""=>""CLIENT"", ""value""=>""GOOGLE""}]}, {}, {}, {}, {}], 
""id""=>""2013-03-09_07-36-49"", 
""number""=>18}]}".replace('=>', ':')

my_hash = JSON.parse(reply)
puts my_hash['builds'] # access the content and further. you can do that.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing a functionality in the jenkins_api_client rubygem, please [open up an issue](https://github.com/arangamani/jenkins_api_client/issues/new) with detailed description and I'll get that implemented as soon as possible.

Thanks,
Kannan (author of jenkins_api_client)

Comment: Thanks Kannan. I would like to contribute from my end if possible. Could you please let me know the steps or link to contribute this to jenkins_api_client.?

Comment: Here is the link to the project hosted on Github: https://github.com/arangamani/jenkins_api_client There is some information on how to contribute in the README. Feel free to contact me with any help you might need.